# Push Notification on iOS with Smartface

Tags: ios, push-notification, smartface.io

I want to add push notification service in Smartface with iOS side. I followed this tutorial.

[Push Notification on Smartface](http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/advanced/push-notifications/#for-ios)
I done with "Before the Code" section. How can I use

http://api.smartface.io/api/PushNotification/Send/{access_token}

How can write backend side?

Answer (score 0):

Smartface push notification sender API s private. You can only use Smartface App Studio for handling push notification from mobile apps

btw, you can find many public push notification services from internet like AWS, Parse, Airbop..